# How to specify line ends and reverse logic in regex?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Actually, I want to find every instance where the line does not end with `successfully;` for e.g.

`...
Lorem Ipsum is simply successfully;
Lorem Ipsum is simply failed;
...`

i.e. *successfully* followed by a *semicolon* and then a *line end*.

So how can I specify `line-ends` in the regex, also how can I specify to only match where it is **not** as per the given pattern (reverse logic)?

Comment: Do you mean `(?m)$(?<!successfully;)`?

Comment: When lookbehind isn't available use: [`^(?!.*successfully;$)`](https://regex101.com/r/HQZInl/1)